# I have a run time error in my JAVA program in my while loop

Tags: java

The code compiles, but when I execute it, it the errors says

> "java.util.NoSuchElementException" and highlights the humidity = input.next();

The sample output is the following:

```
K-Nearest Neighbor Prediction Program:

The values you entered are: sunny cool high true

Comparring the values:  sunny  hot   high false dist = 2 and play = no
Comparring the values:  sunny  hot  high true  dist = 1 and play = no
Comparring the values:  overcast hot  high false dist = 3 and play = yes
Comparring the values:  rainy mild  high false dist = 3 and play = yes
Comparring the values:  rainy cool  normal false dist = 3 and play = yes
```

This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class lab2
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner ("data.txt");
        System.out.println("The values you entered are : ");
        String queryOutlook = "sunny";
        String queryHumidity = "high";
        String queryTemp = "cool";
        String queryVerd = "true";
        String outlook = null;
        String humidity = null;
        String temp = null;
        String verd = null;
        String play= null;
        int distance = 0;
        while(input.hasNext())
        {
            outlook = input.next();
            ***humidity = input.next();***
            temp = input.next();
            verd = input.next();
            if (!outlook.equalsIgnoreCase(queryOutlook) )
            distance++;
            if (!humidity.equalsIgnoreCase(queryHumidity) )
            distance++;
            if (!temp.equalsIgnoreCase(queryTemp) )
            distance++;
            if (!verd.equalsIgnoreCase(queryVerd) )
            distance++;


            System.out.println(outlook + humidity + temp + verd + "\t" + play + distance);
```

Again this program has to do with a the K-nearest neighbor prediction which I have never heard of before since last class period. any help would be appreciated!!!

Comment: my sample output is what I am trying to get my program to look like.

Comment: Your logic is wrong. You are performing input.next() without asking if there is a next element.

Answer (score 4):

```
    while(input.hasNext()) {
        outlook = input.next();
        humidity = input.next();
        temp = input.next();
        verd = input.next();
```

You're checking if the input has ONE next element, and if it does, you get the FOUR next elements. You should check before getting each of them.

Answer (score 3):

The constructor for Scanner() takes a java.io.File as an input.  You're passing it a string.  So your scanner is only scanning the string "data.txt" for your matches, it never actually opened up that file and scanned it.

You would need to do something like this, to start:

```
File f = new File("data.txt");
Scanner input = new Scanner(f);
... // and so on
```

Comment: +1 for noticing the bad constructor call, and not only the bad hasNext() call like I did.

Comment: it highlighted the Scanner input = new Scanner(f) and said

Comment: it highlighted the scanner input and and some the error was: unreported exception java.io.FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

Comment: Google for "java tutorial exceptions", click the first link, and read.